# Bootstrap Modal and Menu lagging on mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mobile, modal-dialog, lag

I have problem with lagging website on mobile phone which was created on bootstrap freamwork.

I found when I deleted background from body of CSS, the lag is smaller.

Here is link: dzik.linuxpl.eu

The lag is exsist when you click MENU or LOGIN button.

Comment: 1. Optimize your main image on https://compressor.io/compress 2. I don't have a lag on iPhone 4S / iOS9.

Comment: 1. I optimazied main image, but it didn't help. 
2. I haven't checked on iOS, only on android and on android phones is lagging.